# how to get name field based on ID in relationship in DJANGO

Tags: django-views

I have chain relationship models such as **Clinic, Doctor and Speciality** Clinic and Doctor have M2M relation and Doctor has specialty ID (foreign key). I'm filtering the doctors based on the Clinic's location (city and area). It is working but problem is that **doctor_set** just return specialit_id but I want the name of speciality
here is my view.

```
class PlanDoctorListView(generic.DetailView):
model = ClinicHospital
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    clinics = ClinicHospital.objects.get(city_id=kwargs.get('city'),area_id=kwargs.get('area'))
    doctors = list(clinics.doctor_set.all().values())
    return JsonResponse(doctors,safe=False)
```

how could I get the name of speciality

here is models.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
name =  models.CharField(max_length = 256)
contact = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
speciality = models.ForeignKey(Speciality, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
clinic_hospital = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicHospital, through='DoctorHospital')

class Speciality(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
code = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Please, add code of your `Doctor` and `Speciality` models

Comment: @weAreStarDust I have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> problem is that doctor_set just return specialit_id but I want the
>   name of speciality here is my view.

Just add related fields you need in `values()`

```
doctors = list(clinics.doctor_set.all().values('name', 'contact', 'speciality__name', ...)
```

Comment: could I get the address field of ClinicHospital along with **list**